# When I print one element of my list[int] it prints as [1] how do I remove the brackets so its just the number (convert list[int] to int) - Python

Tags: python

Hi all I'm new to python and working on a little project. I want to print 100 int's to console; each of the list items have a different probability of occurring as defined in a_listDistribution, I want to output the numbers to the console as int's. below is my code:

```
a_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a_listDistribution = [0.5, 0.4, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125]
att1Int = random.choices(a_list, a_listDistribution)
print(att1Int)
```

Currently the console outputs something similar to this
[0],[0],[1],[0].....

I would like it to output
0,0,1,0

thank you in advance if you can help me!

Comment: How about unpacking the list: ```print(*att1Int)```

Comment: Because you used the default `k=1`, `random.choices` will return a list with exactly 1 item. it doesn't return `[0],[0],[1],[0]`. I don't understand how to get a comma separated list of integers with only one integer. The output can't be `"0,0,1,0"`.

Comment: Maybe `",".join(str(value) for value in random.choices(a_list, a_listDistribution,k=4))` is what you are after?

Answer (score 1):

You could either go with

```
print(att1Int[0]) # getting the first element
```

or

```
print(*att1Int) # unpacking
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple values (a list of lists, basically),
you could do something like this

```
print([a[0] for a in att1Int])
```

or

```
print(', '.join([a[0] for a in att1Int]))
```

If att1Int will always have a single value, you can index or unpack as Gokul Peethu said